# loader to handle this file type ReactJs in maps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack

I am new to react development i am getting this error **you may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type** please check the below image as well

[image]

where i am using this plugin https://github.com/bramus/react-native-maps-directions to make a map in the directions please help me out i had struck in this issue more than 15days

webpackage.config.js

```
var config = {
   entry: './main.js',
   output: {
      path:'/',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },

   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
               presets: ['es2015','stage-0','react']
            }
         },
         {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader:[ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
         },
         {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {}
                    }
                ]
            }
      ]
   }
}
module.exports = config;
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "maps",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.21.0",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.6.0",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "author": "nts",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your implementation, the bare minimum example that re-creates this issue you're facing

Comment: sure i will add that as well

Comment: i had updated question

Comment: please, can i see your `package.json` file? need to check the `babel-*` packages

Comment: Yes i will add that as well

Comment: i had added the Package.json @Murilo Cruz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be related, but you are using `react-native-maps` library here, which is supposed to work only on [react-native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native) (react-native is used to create native mobile applications, while react/react-dom is used for web, library for react-native won't work on plain react and vice versa). It also contains some java and obj-c code. You can try another library for maps, for example [this one](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react)